# Как дождаться полного обновления DOM после ajax запроса и выполнить userscript?

Tags: javascript

господа. Этот usersript загружается из tampermonkey. Скрипт должен выполняться только после того, как DOM обновит контент после ajax запроса. Можно ли как-то обойтись в моем userscript'e без функции setTimeout()?

Пока что решил эту проблему так:

```
function f():
   try {
     //мой код
   } catch(err) {
     setTimeout(f, 1000);
   }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6) Способ 1.

Comment: А о каком обновлении DOM-а идёт речь?

Comment: После ajax запроса, в DOM'e появляются нужные мне кнопки.

Comment: А кодъ де? Кнопки в DOM добавляются синхронно, ждать не надо.

Comment: Это не тот случай. После ajax на этом сайте начинают появляться игровые лобби, а вместе с ними и кнопки для подключения к ним.

Comment: @DmiriiBerrington Вы думаете, Ваш последний комментарий кому-нибудь о чем-нибудь говорит? (особенно слово "лобби")

Comment: Кому-нибудь говорит. После ajax создается список с div'ами, внутри которых и находятся кнопочки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## как отследить появление html элемента в dom

### хорошее решение

при написании асинхронных функций добавления html элементов использовать `async/await` , `Promise` или `callBack`

### не очень

```js
{
    let log = (tsa, ...args) => document.write(args.length > 0 ? String.raw(tsa, ...args) : tsa + '<br>\n')
    function foo(_id, _timeout, _callback) {
        let i = setInterval(() => {
            let el = document.getElementById(_id)
            if (el === null) {
                // --
            } else {
                clearInterval(i)
                log`в дом'е найден элемент с id ${_id}`
                _callback(el)
            }
        }, _timeout)
        return i
    }
    let i = foo('qwa', 200, (_el) => {
        _el.style.color = 'red'
    })
    // -- проверка
    setTimeout(() => {
        log`<div id="qwa">qwa div element</div>`
    }, 3000);
}
```